# SystemVerilog in ModelSim ignores negedge/posedge when monitoring

Tags: fpga, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, modelsim

Using SystemVerilog and ModelSim, I want to monitor the values of some signals in my design when the clock is on its negative edge. Strangely, the code responses on both edges (positive and negative). Here is a minimal working example:

```
`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps
module tb_ex;
logic clk;

always
   begin
     clk = 1;
     #5;
     clk = 0;
     #5;
   end

always @(negedge clk)
   begin
      $monitor($time, "-> clk = %b", clk); 
   end 

endmodule
```

which results in

```
VSIM 40> run
#                    5-> clk = 0
#                   10-> clk = 1
#                   15-> clk = 0
#                   20-> clk = 1
#                   25-> clk = 0
#                   30-> clk = 1
#                   35-> clk = 0
```

[image: wave result]

It seems that the `always @(negedge clk)` is not honored. Even if I put an `if` inside that block,

```
always @(negedge clk)
   begin
      if (clk == 0) begin 
         $monitor($time, "-> clk = %b", clk); 
      end 
   end
```

the result is still the same. How can I make it work as expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2.3 *Continuous monitoring*:

> When a `$monitor` task is invoked with one or more arguments, the simulator sets up a mechanism whereby each time a variable or an expression in the argument list changes value—with the exception of the `$time`, `$stime`, or `$realtime` system functions—the entire argument list is displayed at the end of the time step as if reported by the `$display` task. If two or more arguments change value at the same time, only one display is produced that shows the new values.
>
> Only one `$monitor` display list can be active at any one time; however, a new `$monitor` task with a new display list can be issued any number of times during simulation.

In other words, A `$monitor` task is executed it creates a singleton process that displays the value of the listed variables at the end of the time step when ever one of those variables change.

For your purpose, you should use `$display` or `$strobe` instead of `$monitor`.

`$display` prints the immediate value of variables, while `$strobe` prints the final value in the time step. Neither start an automatic triggering process like `$monitor`.  For details refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2.1 *The display and write tasks* and § 21.2.2 *Strobed monitoring*

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks Greg! May I ask, what's the difference betweeen `$display` and `$strobe`?

Comment: It is in the last paragraph. Example `a=2; $strobe("strobe %0d",a); $display("display %0d",a); a=5;` would print "display 2" then "strobe 5". Try it out on your simulator.